# Groovy - method signature without return type

Tags: groovy

In Groovy could someone explain to me why the following code does not fail despite not having a return type?

```
protected assertRequired(String name, String tag, attrs) {
    if (!attrs.containsKey(name)) {
        throwTagError "Tag [$tag] is missing required attribute [$name]"
    }
    return attrs[name] // conserva la propiedad en attrs.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It does have a return type of `Object`.

`protected ...` is equivalent to `def protected ...`, which has return type of `Object`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, any reference?

Comment: That reference does not contain any about convention of protected methods, another official reference ? Thank you